# How to use VBA to change the way the data list?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Case  Object Equation                                                    Contents           
293   asdg   D0799* (1-(S0191+S0439+S0960+S0560))   * (1-(C0121+C0122)) S0439    S0960  S0560   
296   iknm   D0792* (1-(S0191+S0565+S0567+S0960+S0560)) S0565   S0567   S0960   S0560
298   yiol   D0191* (1-(S0191+S0439+S2820+S0960+S0560)) S0439   S2820   S0960   S0560
```

I was trying to transfer the above data to the below one. There are going to be more rows and columns.

```
Case Object Equation                                                    contents
293  asdg   D0799* (1-(S0191+S0439+S0960+S0560))   * (1-(C0121+C0122))  S0439
293  asdg   D0799* (1-(S0191+S0439+S0960+S0560))   * (1-(C0121+C0122))  S0960
293  asdg   D0799* (1-(S0191+S0439+S0960+S0560))   * (1-(C0121+C0122))  S0560
296  iknm   D0792* (1-(S0191+S0565+S0567+S0960+S0560))                  S0565
296  iknm   D0792* (1-(S0191+S0565+S0567+S0960+S0560))                  S0567
296  iknm   D0792* (1-(S0191+S0565+S0567+S0960+S0560))                  S0960
296  iknm   D0792* (1-(S0191+S0565+S0567+S0960+S0560))                  S0560
298  yiol   D0191* (1-(S0191+S0439+S2820+S0960+S0560))                  S0439
298  yiol   D0191* (1-(S0191+S0439+S2820+S0960+S0560))                  S2820
298  yiol   D0191* (1-(S0191+S0439+S2820+S0960+S0560))                  S0960
298  yiol   D0191* (1-(S0191+S0439+S2820+S0960+S0560))                  S0560
```

The Macro is

```
Sub EquationSegment()
Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim cl As Range, Key As Variant, i&
i = 1
For Each cl In Range("c2:af" & Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row)
    Dic.Add i & ":" & Cells(cl.Row, 1).Value, cl.Value
    i = i + 1

Next cl
i = 2: [an1] = "Equation": [ao1] = "contents"
For Each Key In Dic

    Cells(i, "an").Value = Split(Key, ":")(1)
    Cells(i, "ao").Value = Dic(Key)
    i = i + 1
Next Key
Set Dic = Nothing
End Sub
```

I'm only able to transfer 2 columns. Can anyone help me fix the range issue?

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary can only store key-value pairs and so this isn't a great way of doing this. You would end up have to join and then split strings. You're better using nested loops.

```
Sub EquationSegment()

Dim caseRef As Range
Dim contentsRef As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim outputsRef As Range

    Set caseRef = ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
    Set contentsRef = ActiveSheet.Range("D2:AF2")
    Set outputsRef = ActiveSheet.Range("AN1")
    With outputsRef
        .Value = "Case"
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value = "Object"
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Value = "Equation"
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=3).Value = "Contents"
    End With
    Set outputsRef = outputsRef.Offset(RowOffset:=1)

    Do While caseRef.Value <> ""
        For Each cell In contentsRef
            If cell.Value <> "" Then
                With outputsRef
                    .Value = caseRef.Value
                    .Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value = caseRef.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value
                    .Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Value = caseRef.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Value
                    .Offset(ColumnOffset:=3).Value = cell.Value
                End With
                Set outputsRef = outputsRef.Offset(RowOffset:=1)
            End If
        Next cell
        Set caseRef = caseRef.Offset(RowOffset:=1)
        Set contentsRef = contentsRef.Offset(RowOffset:=1)
    Loop

End Sub
```